# Two related class hierarchies - overriding virtual functions

Tags: c++

Suppose I have this base class:

```
struct Vehicle {
  //"op" stands for the operator of the vehicle
  //examples: pilot, truck driver, etc.
  virtual void insert_op(Op op) = 0;
  //other members...
};
```

And these two subclasses

```
struct Truck : public Vehicle {
  void insert_op(Op op) override {
    //prepare Truck with truck driver
  }
};

struct Airplaine : public Vehicle {
  void insert_op(Op op) override {
    //prepare Airplaine with pilot
  }
};
```

As you guess, this is the other hierarchy:

```
struct Op {};
struct TruckDriver : public Op {};
struct Pilot : public Op {};
```

You already see the problem, don't you? I want to FORCE Truck to accept only TruckDrivers and FORCE airplaines to accept only Pilots, but this is not possible in the current design. C++ does not allow diff parameters for overridden virtuals.

I guess I could do a run-time type check of the type of "Op" in each of the subclass implementations of insert_op, but that sounds like a really ugly solution, plus its not enforced at compile time.

Any ways out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Vehicle` says `virtual void insert_op(Op op)` which means "every vehicle can accept any `Op`".

Therefore, according to your design, a `Truck` isn't a valid candidate for a `Vehicle` subclass because it can't accept *any* `Op` - it can accept only `TruckDriver`s.

Related: [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

---

The problem is in your design, not in implementation of it. I suggest to simplify your class hierarchy. Do you really need so many classes and inheritance? Can you simply go with `Vehicle` and `Op` that have fields identifying their type?

---

Let me further explain the design problem:

Assume some object `A` with a method `manVehicle(Vehicle&)`. `Truck` is a subclass of Vehicle, so it's possible to call this method with an object of type `Truck`.

However, the implementation of `A` doesn't have a clue what concrete types of `Vehicle`s. It only knows that all vehicles have a method `insert_op(Op)`, so it's valid for it to attempt a call like `insert_op(Pilot())` even if the vehicle is actually a `Truck`.

Conclusions:

- Compile-time check isn't even possible
- Runtime check could work...

  - but would only sweep the problem under the rug. An user of `Vehicle`s expects to be able to call `insert_op(Op)` on any `Vehicle`.

A solution would be to modify the `Vehicle` interface to look like:

```
struct Vehicle {
  virtual bool can_insert_op(Op op) = 0;
  virtual void insert_op(Op op) = 0;
};
```

and document it so that the caller would know that `insert_op` can be only called with `Op`s that satisfy `can_insert_op` on the given `Vehicle`. Or something analogous (like a documented exception from `insert_op` "invalid op type for this vehicle") - anything works as long as it's a documented part of this interface.

---

BTW technical remark: You'd probably want these methods to take the `Op` by pointer or reference instead of copying it, to avoid an unnecessary copy as well as [slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: Would you say that such runtime checks are common in well crafted C++ programs?

Comment: I don't think I've seen a hierarchy of classes that would need such checks.

Answer (score 0):

The Vehicle subclasses should each create their their appropriate Operator. There should be no methods to set the operator. Vehicle could have a get_operator method, but that's about it.

I'm guessing this isn't your actual hierarchy (unless you're creating a game or something). If you show your actual hierarchy it might help with suggesting better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

don't find against OOD. if truck driver is a child of driver then its a driver but has other features. in your case the driver is not allowed then its not sub truck driver. If you want to stick with the current design you need to make checks in the start of the fn as you assumed.
polymorphism is designed not to get errors @compile time hence it's dynamic binding at run time not compile time dependent.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
struct Vehicle {
  //"op" stands for the operator of the vehicle
  //examples: pilot, truck driver, etc.
  virtual void insert_op(Op op) = 0;
  virtual bool validate_op(Op op);
  //other members...
};

struct Truck : public Vehicle {
  void insert_op(Op op) override {
    if (validate_op(op)) {
        //prepare Truck with truck driver
    }
  }
  bool validate_op(Op op) override {
    //check if this is a valid truck driver
    return ( typeid(op)==typeid(TruckDriver) );
  }
};
```

You would be able to keep the generic definition of `insert_op` with some validation over it.

Comment: Watch out since the `typeid()` comparison requires an specific subtype of `Op`, `TruckDriver`, not any subtype of TruckDriver, for that, `return dynamic_cast<TruckDriver *>(op)`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to accomplish is legitimate, however, there is no support for a good solution.  It is not a problem of C++ itself, but of Object Orientation:

Your class hierarchy starting at `Vehicle` is *covariant* with respect to the hierarchy of `Op`.  You'd have the same problem if you had a hierarchy of fuels.  Or the nationality of the Ops, etc.

Others have told you explanations of how to accomplish this with run-time checks, but of course, there is always something to be desired.

If you want to accomplish full compile time checking, and the kind of polymorphism you want to have is at compilation time as opposed to runtime, you can use Generic Programming, templates.